# Error when trying to prepare my play-project for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, playframework

When I try "activator eclipse" inside my Play-Project, I am getting this error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typsafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found
```

I added this line to my projec/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typsafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

It's asking me if I want to ignore this but I am aborting.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you 'You must compile your project before running the eclipse command' like they said in the Play documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Eclipse)?

Comment: @Kris Thank you for your answer. I can't compile because activator is not starting because of this error. In a fresh new project it worked, but in this case (basically a fresh project too) i am getting this error.

Comment: I have to correct my previous comment. It worked on a different Mac. On this one I am getting this error even on a new project.